# Problems with Rendering a quad in OpenGL by using indeces

Tags: opengl, indexing, vbo, vao

I want to draw a quad with `OpenGL`, but it doesn't work, since I introduced indexing. Without indexes my code worked fine and I could use `glDrawArrays` :

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600
#define TITLE "Dynamic"

GLFWwindow* window;
int vaoID;


std::vector<float> vertices = {-0.5f, 0.5f, 0,      -0.5f, -0.5f, 0,        0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0,      0.5f, 0.5f, 0};
std::vector<int> indices = { 0, 1, 3,   3, 1, 2 };
void loadToVAO(std::vector<float> vertices, std::vector<int> indices);

void update() {
    loadToVAO(vertices, indices);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_INT, 0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit())
        std::cout << "Couldn't initialize GLFW!" << std::endl;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit())
        std::cout << "GLEW is not working!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Your GL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    //glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    //glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    update();
}

void loadToVAO(std::vector<float> vertices, std::vector<int> indices) {
    GLuint vertexVBO;
    GLuint indicesVBO;
    GLuint vaoID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexVBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &indicesVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices) * sizeof(int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices) * sizeof(float), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, the `sizeof` operator is the problem since it returns the size of the underlying type and not the size of some data a pointer points to. In the line

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices) * sizeof(int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

`sizeof(indices) == sizeof(std::vector<int>)` which is the size of the vector object and **not** the size of the data contained in the vector. The correct code here would be to use `indices.size()` which returns the number of elements in the vector:

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The same goes for the upload of the vertices.

Edit: You should also not pass vectors by value unless it is absolutely necessary. Atm the content of both vectors is copied when you pass them to `loadToVAO`. If you change the function signature to

```
void loadToVAO(std::vector<float>& vertices, std::vector<int>& indices)
```

the vectors are passed by reference and the data is not copied.